# Unable to delete in PHP MYSQL on the basis of email

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a PHP code to delete a record while email is matched, but I am getting error. Although it is very simple but I unable to delete.

My code is.

```
<?php
    include 'condb.php';
    $email1="drmll2325@rainmail.top";
    $sql1 = "delete from users WHERE username=$email1";
    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    if($result1)
    {
           echo "<script>";
           echo "alert('Student deleted succesfully');";
           echo " window.location.href='students.php';";
           echo "</script>";

    }
    else
    {
        echo mysql_error();
        echo "<script>";
        echo "alert('Ooops!!!!! Something goes wrong. Not Deleted.');";
        echo " window.location.href='students.php';";
        echo "</script>";
    }

?>
```

Problem is that when use $email1 as variable in string, it does not work. But when I use email directly as string in query it is working.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@rainmail.top' at line 1

[image]

Comment: Really??  It's 2018 and you're using `mysql_*` functions. Please do not go live with this

Comment: @Akintunde007 I know. But my server is not updated.

Comment: How far behind are your servers? PDO was added in PHP 5.4 and supports back to MySQL 3.x (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and MySQLi was active by PHP 5.3... and *at least* do some data sanitization if you're not going to do it correctly with bound parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct this line:

```
$sql1 = "delete from users WHERE username='$email1'";
```

Comment: But this code is working. Why?                                                                $sql = "delete from st_register WHERE id=$id"; That's why I used above code.

Comment: It's not quoted. Look at your error message. An integer doesn't need quoting, but the SQL engine was likely attempting to treat your string as a field until it found the "@" symbol.

Comment: @arvindkumar you can then mark the question as solved